# How to get `form.field.value` in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in javascript i can validate a form on submit like below:-

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <input type="text" name="uName" id="uName" />
    <input type="password" name="passKey" id="passKey" />
    <input type="submit" name="loginBtn" value="login" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(loginForm){
    if(loginForm.uName.value == ''){
        alert('Please Enter Username');
        loginForm.uName.focus();
    }else if(loginForm.passKey.value == ''){
        alert('Please Enter Password');
        loginForm.passKey.focus();
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried with below jQuery Code

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="uName" id="uName" />
    <input type="password" name="passKey" id="passKey" />
    <input type="submit" name="loginBtn" value="login" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function(loginForm){
        if(loginForm.uName.val() == ''){
            alert('Please enter username');
            loginForm.uName.focus();
        }else if(loginForm.passKey.val() == ''){
            alert('Please enter username');
            loginForm.passKey.focus();
        }else {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

But not works me... please help me...!

Comment: You're trying to use jQuery methods on DOM elements. You need to wrap them in `jQuery` first.

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks for the quick reply... Don't understood what wrap them in jQuery :( can you explain me please?

Comment: You need to wrap your code in `jQuery(function($){ ... })`.

Comment: Argument in submit callback is not the element it is the event. Try it this way instead http://jsfiddle.net/4R5AP/

Comment: @rkaartikeyan you are welcome. BTW @:user2673069 answer has a point though. Since it is id you could just access it with `$('#uName')` or `document.getElementById('uName')` assuming you follow the principle that ids must be unique.

Comment: I Up Vote the both answer but i was expect how you did this.fieldname.value :) i like this way. So please post your code as answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

like this?

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    if( $('#uName').val() == ''){
        alert('empty');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TTmYk/

the submit form has a typo in my fiddle u might need to fix that

Comment: Thanks for your answer... i knew this way... but trying to do like java... form.fieldname.valu :) i like that method.

Comment: jQuery has one form for accessing input values, it is `.val()`, there is no alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

See the Form Fields jQuery Plugin:
https://github.com/webarthur/jquery-fields

You can use the plugin as follows:

```
var form = $('form#id_form').fields();

form.name.val('Arthur');
form.age.hide();
form.description.css('height', 200);
```

Or this way:

```
var form = $('form#id_form').fieldValues();

form.name('Arthur');
form.age(29);
form.description('Web developer.');

var name = form.name();
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument in the submit callback function is not the element instead it is the event. So  inside the callback `this` represents the form element so you could just do `this.uName.value` and you can avoid the use of id as well. 
So

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
        if(this.uName.value == ''){
            alert('Please enter username');
            this.uName.focus();
        }else if(this.passKey.value == ''){
            alert('Please enter username');
            this.passKey.focus();
        }else {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzgcV/)**

Plus `val()` is jquery method, and in plain javascript you would use `value` and in this case that should be sufficient enough.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    var $username = $('#uName'),
        $password = $('#passKey');

    $('form').submit(function() {

        if ($username.val() == '') {
            alert('Please enter username');
            $username.focus();
        } else if($password.val() == '') {
            alert('Please enter username');
            $password.focus();
        } else {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Some points you need to keep in mind:

1. If you will work with the DOM you should wrap your code inside a `jQuery(function() { ... });` block.
2. If you want to access a DOM element with jQuery you need to *select* it before using `$(...)`.